# Wix Not overwriting my app.config

Tags: c#, wix

Hi everyone i'm using wix to install my current application and it successfully installs everything and the initial version of the installer has NeverOverwrite="yes" in the installer but in a future version I realized that i can overwrite it everytime but when i remove the NeverOverwrite attribute in the future version of the installer it doesn't overwrite the configuration. Do i have to change the guid or do a major upgrade to get the configuration file to get updated with the latest version of my installer?

Comment: this link might be helpful - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2441651/wix-overwrites-config-files-during-setup-how-can-i-avoid-this

Answer (score 1):

When performing an upgrade the installer only replaces assemblies and associated files of assemblies that have changed from the current installation.

App.config files are associated with particular executable assemblies, which, if it has not had its version number increased in any way will not be updated on the installation machine (as the installer detects no change in version numbers).

You could either increase the version number of the executable associated with the app.config file, or use Orca to [forcefully overwrite](http://amassani.wordpress.com/2009/02/28/force-overwrite-files-with-windows-installer/) the app.config.

Comment: I'm guessing that you could use the `RemoveFile` element (child of `Component`) and it would have the same effect as manually editing the msi in Orca. I haven't tried it though.

Comment: Windows Installer doesn't see any association between files unless they are in the same component. All files in an assembly should be in the same component. (Most assemblies have only one file, anyway.) For app.config files see this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3203421/2226988).